# how to extract specific part of character vector in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have file names like this as a character vector;

```
filenames <- c('1194-1220-1479-891--(133.07).RDS','1194-1221-1421-891--(101.51).RDS')
```

Don't want to have digits in pharanthesis and want to have digits "/" separated.
So the desired output is;

```
filenames_desired <- c('1194/1220/1479/891','1194/1221/1421/891')
```

I tried with `gsub` but didn't know how to remove digits in pharanthesis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using stringr, looking around `(?=-)` meaning: has to be followed by a dash and sapply:

```
filenames <- c('1194-1220-1479-891--(133.07).RDS','1194-1221-1421-891--(101.51).RDS')

sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(filenames, "\\d+(?=-)"), 
       paste0, 
       collapse = "/") 

[1] "1194/1220/1479/891" "1194/1221/1421/891"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a single `sub()` call here:

```r
filenames <- c("1194-1220-1479-891--(133.07).RDS",
               "1194-1221-1421-891--(101.51).RDS")

output <- sub("(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+).*", "\\1/\\2/\\3/\\4", filenames)
output

[1] "1194/1220/1479/891" "1194/1221/1421/891"
```

Comment: The replacement is totally necessary.

Comment: Oh sorry. I did not anticipate the `sub`. So using `str_extract(filenames, '\\d*\\-\\d*\\-\\d*\\-\\d*')` which needs `stringr` package, would work without replacement!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `gsub` with `\\--.*`: removes everything after and including `--`:

```
gsub('\\--.*', '', filenames)

[1] "1194-1220-1479-891" "1194-1221-1421-891"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the first 18 characters of your names are the base of your final names; so, you can use the following code

```
# Initial names
  filenames <- ('1194-1220-1479-891--(133.07).RDS','1194-1221-1421-891--(101.51).RDS')

# Extract the first 18 elements of "filenames"
  nam <- substr(filenames, 1, 18)
# Replace "-" by "/"
  final.names <- str_replace_all(nam, "-", "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strsplit` to extract the first element from each list and then use `gsub`:

```
gsub('-', '/', sapply(strsplit(filenames, '--'), `[[`, 1))
```

which will yield

```
#"1194/1220/1479/891" "1194/1221/1421/891"
```